# ReactJS based web app doesn't render on Facebook and IG's in app browser

Tags: reactjs, facebook, mobile, instagram

I have a site written in ReactJS (CRA).  It runs fine on Chrome, Safari, and FF, but clicking on our URL from inside the native mobile FB/IG app renders a blank screen.   Does anyone know what's going on?  Or, how to debug this?